# SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal - using a unique separator

Tags: python, csv

I am getting the above error for the code:

```
from_csv = pd.readcsv('2968986.log.txt',sep= r'^\')
```

The text file I'm parsing uses ^\ as a separator, using Python 2.7 on OsX. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You are escaping your end single quote `'`

> A "raw string literal" is a slightly different syntax for a string
>   literal, in which a backslash, \, is taken as meaning "just a
>   backslash" (except when it comes right before a quote that would
>   otherwise terminate the literal) [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2081708/1771644)

```
from_csv = pd.readcsv('2968986.log.txt',sep= r'^\\')
```

This escapes the escape character and allows you to post a backslash.
You can find all the other [escape characters here](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals)

Comment: Hey thanks, that did the trick! I thought the 'r' in front precluded the need for the additional backslash... still wrapping my head around that.

Comment: @shawnkumar If the `r` allowed you to put a quote inside the string without escaping it, how would it know which quotes are inside, and which one is the end of the string?

Comment: @Barmar, thanks for the edit and you are correct
Its mentioned in another post **[quote]**
"A "raw string literal" is a slightly different syntax for a string literal, in which a backslash, \, is taken as meaning "just a backslash" (except when it comes right before a quote that would otherwise terminate the literal) **[/quote]**
[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081640/what-exactly-do-u-and-r-string-flags-do-in-python-and-what-are-raw-string-l)